# ¿Cómo puedo traducir a otro idioma (inglés) el sitio web que estoy desarrollando?

Tags: javascript, html5, traducción

Agradecería mucho su ayuda. He estado desarrollando un sitio web (html5, css, js) y quiero, por medio de un enlace, traducir el sitio web a inglés. Gracias.

Comment: Quieres tener una traducción multi-idiomas para tu página web ??? Por que eso es solo copiar páginas, en un enlace nuevo, y traducir el texto.

Comment: Exactamente. Por ahora, solo quiero que se traduzca de español a inglés y viceversa. ¿O sea que solo debo enlazar las páginas de un idioma a las páginas del otro idioma?

Comment: Exacto, generalmente querrás trabajar en el idioma base primero, y luego crear un subenlace al idioma que prefieras. Por eso es que casi siempre vez la misma página, pero con el agregado `/es/` o `/en/` según corresponda

Comment: Esto te podría guiar -> https://www.jimdo.com/es/blog/crear-pagina-web-multilenguaje/

Comment: Te lo agradezco. :)

Comment: Lo trabajaré como respuesta para que la puedas marcar.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Para la realización de páginas web multi-idioma
Basta con realizar una subcategoría en tus enlaces dependiendo del idioma.
Ejemplos:

> [www.mipagina.com](http://www.mipagina.com) (original) 
> [www.mipagina.com/es/](http://www.mipagina.com/es/) (español) 
> [www.mipagina.com/en/](http://www.mipagina.com/en/) (inglés)

Luego solo basta con copiar la página base, y trabajarla dentro de esos enlaces.
Recuerda editar todo lo visible, texto, botones, menús, enlaces, etc.
Puedes ir relajado y trabajar página a página tu traducción. 
Además recuerda dejar el acceso a los idiomas visible y cómodo para el usuario 
Evita usar traductores, dado que son imprecisos, y podrían terminar tergiversando el texto que quieres entregar.